# Negative sobolev space as a subspace of distrbutions

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consider the negative Sobolev space $W^{-k,p}(\Omega)=(W^{k,q}_0(\Omega))^*$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $1/p+1/q=1$.

Since $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega) \subset W^{k,p}_0(\Omega),$ clearly an element of $W^{-k,p}(\Omega)$ maps $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. How to prove that it is a disbribution. In otherwords, does continuity wrt $W^{k,q}$ norm imply continuity in the inductive limit topology on $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$?

A clean proof is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u \in W^{-k,p}(\Omega)$ then for every compact set $K$ and  $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ with $\operatorname{supp}(\phi) \subset K$ we have:
\begin{align}
\langle u,\phi\rangle& \leq  C \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} \|D^{\alpha}\phi\|_{L^q(K)} \right)\\& \leq C \mu(K)^{1/q} \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k }
\|D^{\alpha} \phi\|_{L^{\infty}(K)} \\&:=C_K \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k }
\|D^{\alpha} \phi\|_{L^{\infty}(K)} ,
\end{align}
which implies that $u$ is a distribution of order less than or equals $k$.